# excel VBA selecting multiple cells

Tags: vba, excel

Good day,

I'm looking for assistance in figuring out my problem. I wanted to find a cell in Column A that contains the text "Grand Total". Find is the keyword since it may sometimes entered in A14, or A12, or A20. When the text is found, I wanted to select that cell, and the next cell in column B. Let's say the text is found in A14, then select A14 and B14.

In that way, I would like to continue and edit the format as font = bold, fill color, and font color (I will figure it out soon).

I can't seem to find a code that will help me so I appreciate any help. Below is a code I found but it seems to be not working FOR ME. Credits for this code from this link: [How to select a range of rows using two variables in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16346275/how-to-select-a-range-of-rows-using-two-variables-in-vba)

```
Dim Consultant1 As Integer, Consultant2 As Integer
Dim ConsultantRange As Range

Dim rngFind As Range
Set rngFind = Columns("A:A").Find(What:="Grand Total", After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)

If Not rngFind Is Nothing Then
    Consultant1 = rngFind.row + 1
End If

Set rngFind = Columns("A:A").Find(What:="Grand Total", After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)

If Not rngFind Is Nothing Then
    Consultant2 = rngFind.row - 1
End If

If Consultant1 > 0 And Consultant2 > 0 Then
    Set ConsultantRange = Range(Cells(Consultant1, 2), Cells(Consultant2, 2))
    With ConsultantRange.Selection.Font.Bold = True
    End With
End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim rngFind As Range
    Set rngFind = Range("A:A").Find(What:="Grand Total", After:=Range("A1"))
    rngFind.Resize(1, 2).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Oh my so 'Resize' is the code I'm particularly looking for. This is great! Thank you Gary's Student!